# 'Returning' if statement if user says 'no'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm still quite new to python so I've decided to create a program that asks the user what application they want to open if they type it in.

If the user types in anything else that's not an application in the prompts code, I want to have the question to 'reset' or 'return' to it's original state so I don't have to keep opening up a new terminal tab to achieve this but I don't know how!

Here's some code just to get an idea:

```
import os
import subprocess

print ('What do you want to open?')

prompt = raw_input('> ')

if prompt == 'safari':
    print('Opening Safari...')
    subprocess.call(
    ["/usr/bin/open", "-W", "-n", "-a", "/Applications/Safari.app"]
    )
else:
    print ('No Applications have been selected!')
    #Return to the original question#
```

Answer (score 1):

What about a `while True` that will loop forever?

```py
import os
import subprocess

while True:
    print ('What do you want to open?')

    prompt = raw_input('> ')

    if prompt == 'safari':
        print('Opening Safari...')
        subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/open", "-W", "-n", "-a", "/Applications/Safari.app"])
    elif prompt == 'quit':
        break # will break out of the while loop and exit the program
    else:
        print ('No Applications have been selected!')
        #Return to the original question#
```

As @FedericoS suggests, use the `break` statement to break out of the loop when you need.

Note that your program can still crash if exceptions occur. To make sure it doesn't, have a look at exception handling in Python.

Also note that due to the blocking aspect of `subprocess.call`, the script will only loop back when the launched process exits. Consider using `subprocess.Popen` instead if you wish to immediately loop back.

Comment: Adding to this: if you want to get out of the loop at some point, you just have to `break`. An alternative would be to have a sentinel variable that starts out as True, `while condition:` and simply make it False under any condition that should exit the loop. In this case you can still execute any further instructions and the loop will exit at the end, instead of immediately.

Comment: Yes, that's done the trick. Thank you! Could you explain how this while loop causes it to only loop when the user says no? I can't figure out the logic of it plus I'm that new haha.

Comment: It loops inconditionnally, whatever the user answers. If you have the impression that it doesn't loop when the user writes 'safari', it's because the call to `subprocess` is blocking and waits for the user to close the application. Close safari and you'll see the program looping again.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Thank you guys for the help, much appreciated.